# ¿Como compartir una carpeta entre host y guesst en virt-manager?

Tags: linux, windows

espero que este bien.
Ante todo dejo una imagen para que vean exactamente a lo que me refiero:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como verán estoy queriendo hacer que la carpeta **CompartidosXP** se comparta entre mi host linux y el sistema anfritrión que es un XP.

El tema es que no consigo hacer que el windows xp pueda reconocerlo, ya que no encuentro ni drivers de virtio a pesar de que bajé los oficiales en formato iso en Fedora.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias buscar el recurso compartido en las redes Windows. Ahí debiera aparecerte la máquina desde donde estás compartiendo el recurso y el recuerso que estás compartiendo.